# Calculate percent of values based on column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the percent of values in a column based on a list of unique values in another column. My dataframe has the following structure:

```
property_state_code | converted
   --------------------------------
       NY                converted
       TX                converted
       TX                Not Converted
       CA                Not Converted
       MO                converted
```

The results I want would be something like:

```
states | conversion_pct
    -----------------------
      NY        1
      TX        .5
      CA        0
      MO        1
```

My code thus far is below. The error I am getting is

> "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
> a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

In the line where I am trying to do the pct calculation (pct = ...). I am not sure where in that line this error is occurring, so any insight or help would be appreciated!

```
states = []
for val in results.property_state_code:
  if val not in states:
    states.append(val)
print(states)

conversion_pct = []
for state in states:
  if results['property_state_code'] == state:
    pct = (results['converted'].value_counts()['converted']) / ((results['converted'].value_counts()['converted']) + (results['converted'].value_counts()['Not Converted']))
    conversion_pct.append(pct)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = (
 df['converted'].eq('converted')
  .groupby(df['property_state_code'].rename('states'), sort=False)
  .mean().reset_index(name='conversion_pct')
)
```

Output:

```
  states  conversion_pct
0     NY             1.0
1     TX             0.5
2     CA             0.0
3     MO             1.0
```